# Submit form additions or changes using AJAX, and display result

Tags: javascript, validation, form, ajax

I am submitting my form using ajax. Here is the actual code:

```
// generic ajax caller
function ajaxHandler(url, data, options)
{
    return $.ajax($.extend({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                return error;
            },
        }, options))

};



   // This code handles course submission form 

     $('#add-course').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    ajaxHandler(form.url, form.serialize()).then(function (result) {

        console.log('#############');

        $('.field-error, .success, .error').remove();
        if(result.errorType == "fieldErrors")
        {
            // handle field errors
            $.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key, value);
                $('<span class="field-error"> ' + value.msg + '</span>').insertBefore('#' + value.param);
            });
        }

        else if(result.errorType == "formErrors")
        {
            // handle form errors
            $('<p class="error">' + result.message + '</p>').insertBefore(form);
        }

        else
        {
            // success
            form[0].reset();
            $('<p><span class="success">' + result.message + '</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
        }

    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        $('<p ><span class="error">Error connecting server</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
    });

});


// Here is code which handles update course form
$('#change-course').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    ajaxHandler(form.url, form.serialize()).then(function (result) {

        $('.field-error, .success, .error').remove();
        if(result.errorType == "fieldError")
        {
            // handle field errors
            $.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key, value);
                $('<span class="field-error"> ' + value.msg + '</span>').insertBefore('#' + value.param);
            });
        }

        else if(result.errorType == "formError")
        {
            // handle form errors
            $('<p><span class="form-error">' + result.message + '</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
        }

        else
        {
            // success
            $('<p><span class="success">' + result.message + '</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
        }

    })
        .fail(function (error) {
            $('<p><span class="error">Error connecting server</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
        });
});
```

As you can see the structure of add/update form is almost the same. How can I refactor all this?

Comment: Why are you using `$.extend()` to merge the `options` parameter of `ajaxHandler()` with the rest of the data? You don't seem to be passing anything to `options` either time you call `ajaxHandler()`...

Comment: There are other actions which uses this , that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the code duplication can be taken care of by simply creating `success` and `failure` functions to handle the ajax response for both your forms. Additionally, if you're only sometimes going to pass a value to `options` in the `ajaxHandler` function, you should check if it's undefined.

```
// generic ajax caller
function ajaxHandler(url, data, options) {
  var ajaxOptions = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      return data;
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      return error;
    }
  };
  return (options === undefined) ? $.ajax(ajaxOptions) : $.ajax($.extend(ajaxOptions, options));
};

function success(result, form, reset) {
  $('.field-error, .success, .error').remove();
  if (result.errorType == "fieldErrors") {
    // handle field errors
    $.each(result.data, function(key, value) {
      console.log(key, value);
      $('<span class="field-error"> ' + value.msg + '</span>').insertBefore('#' + value.param);
    });
  } else if (result.errorType == "formErrors") {
    // handle form errors
    $('<p class="error">' + result.message + '</p>').insertBefore(form);
  } else {
    // success
    if (reset) {
      form[0].reset();
    }
    $('<p><span class="success">' + result.message + '</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
  }
}

function failure(form) {
  $('<p><span class="error">Error connecting server</span></p>').insertBefore(form);
}

// This code handles course submission form 
$('#add-course').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  ajaxHandler(form.url, form.serialize())
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log('#############');
      success(result, form, false);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      failure(form);
    });
});

// Here is code which handles update course form
$('#change-course').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  ajaxHandler(form.url, form.serialize())
    .then(function(result) {
      success(result, form, true);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      failure(form);
    });
});
```